# R: Reorder data frame rows by row index

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, rows

Suppose I have a given dataframe like in the example. How can I reorder the rows so that row number 2 is at the end of the dataframe. Ideally with dplyr. Thanks!
[image: example]

mycode:

```
name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "hans")
age <- c(23, 41, 32, 66)
something <- c(1,2,3, 6)
something_more <- c(4,5,6, 9)

df <- data.frame(name, age, something, something_more )
```

Comment: you could create a new column with the sorting criteria and then use dplyr::arrange() to order/sort by that.

Comment: `df %>%  arrange(row_number() == 2)`

Comment: Thank you  27 ϕ 9. That's what was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Not dplyr but easy: `df <- rbind(df[ -2, ], df[ 2, ])`

Comment: Or without `dplyr/rbind`  `df[c(1,3:nrow(df), 2),  ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `slice` to drop/select specific rows.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% slice(-2) %>% bind_rows(df %>% slice(2))

#   name age something something_more
#1   Jon  23         1              4
#2 Maria  32         3              6
#3  hans  66         6              9
#4  Bill  41         2              5
```